# TYPO3 caching and redirectToUri

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a `saveDataAction`. It is marked as non-cached in the `ext_localconf.php`.
The saving works when I try it right after clearing the cache. The second time, the action is running, just the redirect works, but the data won't be saved.
Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/sLhtXrKL

Comment: your question is maybe asked too broad. Please consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the `HttpUtility::redirect` method:

```
$cObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\ContentObject\\ContentObjectRenderer');
$loginUrl = $cObj->typoLink_URL(array(
    'parameter' => $settings['thankyouPage'],
    'useCacheHash' => TRUE,
    'forceAbsoluteUrl' => FALSE
));
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\HttpUtility::redirect($loginUrl);
```